# Javascript won't do cross domain request from django

Tags: javascript, django, cross-domain, yql

Hi here is an odd problem. I am trying to serve the below index.htm file with django. When you click the button, the page (not the server) does a cross-domain request. If I load the index file direct in a browser it works. However, if I serve it with django, I get "An error occurred trying to load the resource" in the same browser (Safari). I am using (YQL) this method for cross domain requests: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/static/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/static/jquery.xdomainajax.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.google.com',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(res) {
        var headline = $(res.responseText).text();
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
        },
    beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie("csrftoken"));
        }
    }
    });
}
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in your ajax function:

```
    beforeSend : function(xhr, settings) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", getCookie("csrftoken"));
        }
    },
```

And also this function in your script:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
```

:D

Comment: Joao, thanks for your reply. I edited my code (see above) to include your code. However, it still doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?